# C: string-literal - question

Tags: c, string-literals

Is only in `char *ptr = "Hello World"` a string literal or are both `"Hello World"` string literals?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    char array[] = { "Hello World" };
    char *ptr = "Hello World";

    printf( "%s\n", array );
    printf( "%s\n", ptr );

    printf( "%c\n", *array );
    printf( "%c\n", *ptr );

    printf( "%c\n", array[1] );
    printf( "%c\n", ptr[1] );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

# Hello World
# Hello World
# H
# H
# e
# e
```

Comment: I see 8 string literals: `"Hello World"` twice, `"%s\n"` also twice, and `"%c\n"` four times. If they occupy 8 distinct regions of memory or 3 (or anything in between) is unspecified by the Standard: implementations are free to do as they like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"Hello world"` is always a string literal, no matter what you do with it.

`char *ptr = "Hello World";` defines a pointer which points to space which is often not modifiable (so you should handle it like a `const char *` and your compiler might actually complain if you don't).

`char array[] = { "Hello World" };` creates the array on the stack so it's modifiable and roughly equal to `char array[sizeof("Hello World")]; strcpy(array, "Hello World");`

Comment: Does `char array[] =  "hello world"`  store in stack , i mean does each character `h , e , l , l , o , w , o ,r ,l ,d `, gets stored in stack , and is `char array [] = "hello world"` is equivalent to `char array[] = {h,e,l,l,o,w,o,r,l,d}` ;

Answer (score 5):

`"Hello World"` is a string literal - no matter whether you assign it to a `char *` or copy it to a `char []`

`char * ptr = "Hello World";` should really be `const char * ptr = "Hello World";` - String literals may be unmodifiable (in readonly memory), and using a `const char *` is an extra safeguard against modification.

`char array[] = { "Hello World" };` is safe - this copies the string literal from the potential readonly memory into a local variable.

Comment: Actually it should really be `const char * const` in this example, as `ptr` is not modified either. :)

Comment: @GrahamS: That'd just add confusion to what's important here, that the literal should be treated as const.

Comment: True enough, but I think it is an important sub-point. If we are declaring char pointers to string literals then we should generally use `const char * const MyLiteral = "My Literal Text";` as that says `MyLiteral` points to `"My Literal Text"` and always will.

Answer (score 2):

`"Hello World"` is a string literal.

In case of `char *ptr = "Hello World";` `ptr` is pointing to `"Hello World"` which is present in read only location. Any attempt to modify the it via `ptr` would invoke undefined behaviour.

Whereas in `char array[] = { "Hello World" };` content of the string literal is copied onto a stack. You are allowed to modify those content without invoking UB.

BTW ISO C99 (Section 6.4.5/6) says

> It is unspeciﬁed whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the appropriate values.

That means it is unspecified whether the compiler treats two(or more) occurrences of `"Hello World"` distinct.

Answer (score 1):

Only the `"Hello World"` themselves are string literals.

`ptr` is a pointer to `char` initialized with the address of the first element of the string literal.

`array` is an array and not a literal.

Answer (score 0):

`"Hello World"` is a string literal, regardless of where in the code it appears. Neither `ptr` nor `array` are string literals.

Answer (score 0):

This is compiled to a string literal in the read only section.

```
        .section        .rodata
.LC0:
        .string "Hello World"
```

Both occurences are combined into one array... at least on my machine with gcc.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare char array[] you are declaring an array of chars (which is accessible to be both read and written), and this array is initialized to some sequence of characters

If you declare char * ptr, you are declaring a pointer that points directly to some constant literal(not a copy) and you can just read it